# Does anyone know what day(s) the Dacian calendar year started on?

Tags: ancient-history, calendar

The Dacian calendar is supposedly one of the most accurate calendars of ancient times. I've found generalities about the overall composition of the calendar, like it has three seasons, instead of 4. Summer is 21 weeks, then autumn and winter are 13 weeks each.

> "The Dacian calendar was based on a 13-year cycle, ending with a correction day. The same calculations show that a Dacian year was 47 weeks. Users of this calendar scored 8 weeks of 8 days, followed by a week of 7 days, three weeks of 8 days and a week of 6 days. Consequently, the year had, in Dacians, when 365, when 364, when 367 days, exactly in that order. The year did not start on a fixed date, as in the Gregorian calendar today, but on the same day of the week." From [Steem](https://steemit.com/romania/@lazarescu.irinel/the-dacians-calculated-the-length-of-the-year-more-precisely-than-the-mayans-the-difference-from-solar-tropical-year-is-only-0).

In my net research, I have not found the approximate day(s) the Dacian new year starts on in comparison to the Gregorian calendar. As an example, the first day of the Persian calendar, known as Nowruz (نوروز), is equivalent to March 21st of the Gregorian calendar, or Chinese New Year, Zhōngguó Xīn Nián (中國新年), is on a date between January 21st and February 20th on the Gregorian Calendar. Any help finding this group of days for the Dacian New year would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is so unclear about this question? It basically asks "when is Dacian new year"?

Comment: Given that some Romanian professors claim to have completely understood the Dacian calendar, this should not be too hard to figure out (if one accepts their interpretation of the calendar). Of course it would be quite interesting to compare their interpretation with ancient accounts, if any exist

Comment: The linked and quoted article seems to be based on a 1980 paper named "Calendarul de la Sarmizegetusa Regia" by Şerban Bobancu, Cornel Samoilă, Emil Poenaru.

Comment: I don't understand why my question was closed. Will it remain closed? @Jan seems to understand my question. What do I need to do to make it clearer?

Comment: I don't see the problem with the question. Regarding the start of the year, from what I understand about the research into the site, they looked at how the Dacians divided a sequence of days into years, and compared the average length of a Dacian year against an astronomical year. It's possible to do this without knowing when the year started. Even if the passage of time is related to elements in a stone calendar, that may not tell you when a year started, particularly if the calendar counts months or days and doesn't mark the start of years. Just a guess though.

Comment: @StuartF: If I understand correctly, there was something about seasons, so this might give an idea about the start of the year. However, my superficial impression is that this is all quite speculative. Their interpretation of a Dacian year seems quite convoluted, which makes me wonder what exactly the factual basis for their theory is and whether there might not be alternative and simpler explanations.

Comment: The 21 + 13 = 34 pillars of the inner circle represent the northern and southern constellations. [Ptolemy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy)'s [Almagest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almagest) lists 21 + 15 = 36.